# Selecting data from a pipe delimited column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pipe, extract, delimited

I have a column `ClientInformation` in a Table `CurrentOrders` that contains a pipe delimited string:

```
5275=7147|109=62F36|5075=BCRM|12221=PortwareALGO1
```

each `number=` is a FIX tag that I want to name as its own column and need to be able to use in a `SELECT` statement and `WHERE` clause.

I hacked something that let me identify rows i needed, but I can't use in `SELECT` or `WHERE`...

```
   (LEFT (RIGHT(ClientInformation, ( LEN(ClientInformation) - (PATINDEX('%109=%',ClientInformation) + 3) )),
    PATINDEX('%|%', RIGHT(ClientInformation, ( LEN(ClientInformation) - (PATINDEX('%109=%',ClientInformation) + 2) ))) -2))as AccountID
```

I am assuming i need to break each `number=` out into its own temp column in my table, but I am having difficulty finding an explanation I can follow.

So, each of these values I would like as follows:

```
5275=7147|109=62F36|5075=BCRM|12221=PortwareALGO1

5275= as ClientBook
109= as AccountID
5075= as Broker ID
12221= as RouteTrace
```

Comment: ignore, I see now it's for SQL Server (patindex)

Answer (score 0):

The following approach uses multiple CROSS APPLYs because the alias given to each calculation is reusable in the next CROSS APPLY and overall this helps simplify the code (IMHO).

```
SELECT
      ClientBook
    , AccountID
    , BrokerID
    , RouteTrace
FROM CurrentOrders
      CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT
                  PATINDEX('%|%', ClientInformation)
                , LEN(ClientInformation)
      ) ca1 (p1, len1)
      CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT
                  p1 + PATINDEX('%|%', SUBSTRING(ClientInformation, p1 + 1, len1))
      ) ca2 (p2)
      CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT
                  p2 + PATINDEX('%|%', SUBSTRING(ClientInformation, p2 + 1, len1))
      ) ca3 (p3)
      CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT
                  SUBSTRING(ClientInformation, 1, p1 - 1)
                , SUBSTRING(ClientInformation, p1 + 1, p2 - p1 - 1)
                , SUBSTRING(ClientInformation, p2 + 1, p3 - p2 - 1)
                , SUBSTRING(ClientInformation, p3 + 1, len1)
      ) ca4 (s1, s2, s3, s4)
      CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT
                  LEFT(s1, PATINDEX('%=%', s1) - 1)
                , LEFT(s2, PATINDEX('%=%', s2) - 1)
                , LEFT(s3, PATINDEX('%=%', s3) - 1)
                , LEFT(s4, PATINDEX('%=%', s4) - 1)
      ) ca5 (ClientBook, AccountID, BrokerID, RouteTrace)
;
| CLIENTBOOK | ACCOUNTID | BROKERID | ROUTETRACE |
|------------|-----------|----------|------------|
|       5275 |       109 |     5075 |      12221 |
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f85bc/3